# Flatten + (~self-join) a spark data-frame with array of struct in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Input data-frame:

```
{
  "F1" : "A",
  "F2" : "B",
  "F3" : [
            {
              "name" : "N1",
              "sf1" : "val_1",
              "sf2" : "val_2"
            },
            {
              "name" : "N2",
              "sf1" : "val_3",
              "sf2" : "val_4"
            }
         ],
  "F4" : {
        "SF1" : "val_5",
        "SF2" : "val_6",
        "SF3" : "val_7"
  }
}
```

Desired output:

```
[
  {
    "F1" : "A",
    "F2" : "B",

    "F3_name" : "N1",
    "F3_sf1" : "val_1",
    "F3_sf2" : "val_2",
    
    "F4_SF1" : "val_7",
    "F4_SF2" : "val_8",
    "F4_SF3" : "val_9",
  },
  {
    "F1" : "A",
    "F2" : "B",

    "F3_name" : "N2",
    "F3_sf1" : "val_3",
    "F3_sf2" : "val_4",
    
    "F4_SF1" : "val_7",
    "F4_SF2" : "val_8",
    "F4_SF3" : "val_9",
  }
]
```

`F3` is an array of struct. The new data-frame is supposed to be flat and have converted this single row into one or more rows(2 in this example) based on the number of items in `F3`.

I am new to Spark & Scala. Any thought on how of achieve this transformation will be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also first use an `explode`.  Then, you could extract and rename the fields with a series of aliases (e.g., `$"F3.name" as "F3_name"`):

```
scala> case class NameSF(name: String, sf1: String, sf2: String)
defined class NameSF

scala> case class SF(SF1: String, SF2: String, SF3: String)
defined class SF

scala> case class F(F1: String, F2: String, F3: Array[NameSF], F4: SF)
defined class F

scala> val elem = F("A",
     |              "B",
     |              Array(NameSF("N1", "val_1", "val_2"), NameSF("N2", "val_3", "val_4")),
     |              SF("val_5", "val_6", "val_7"))
elem: F = F(A,B,[LNameSF;@2939bfa0,SF(val_5,val_6,val_7))

scala> val df = spark.createDataset(Seq(elem)).toDF
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [F1: string, F2: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.withColumn("F3", explode($"F3")).select($"F1",
     |                                            $"F2",
     |                                            $"F3.name" as "F3_name",
     |                                            $"F3.sf1" as "F3_sf1",
     |                                            $"F3.sf2" as "F3_sf2",
     |                                            $"F4.SF1" as "F4_SF1",
     |                                            $"F4.SF2" as "F4_SF2",
     |                                            $"F4.SF3" as "F4_SF3").show
+---+---+-------+------+------+------+------+------+                            
| F1| F2|F3_name|F3_sf1|F3_sf2|F4_SF1|F4_SF2|F4_SF3|
+---+---+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  A|  B|     N1| val_1| val_2| val_5| val_6| val_7|
|  A|  B|     N2| val_3| val_4| val_5| val_6| val_7|
+---+---+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inline` to explode and expand F3, and `*` to expand F4:

```
val df2 = df.selectExpr("F1","F2","inline(F3)","F4.*")

df2.show
+---+---+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| F1| F2|name|  sf1|  sf2|  SF1|  SF2|  SF3|
+---+---+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  A|  B|  N1|val_1|val_2|val_5|val_6|val_7|
|  A|  B|  N2|val_3|val_4|val_5|val_6|val_7|
+---+---+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```